# Java: Can't repaint ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I have a `JFrame`, and inside `JFrame` is a `JPanel`, and inside `JPanel` are 12 `JButton`s. I have set an `ImageIcon` for each button.

Then, I need to give a `JButton` a new `ImageIcon`. I tried this:

```
buttons[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("path/to/new/icon"));
```

But it didn't work. Also tried:

```
buttons[0].revalidate();
my_jpanel.revalidate();
```

So what am I forgetting about? Why it doesn't repaint?

Comment: There is no need for the revalidate(), the button will repaint itself. If it isn't working then 1) the path and/or filename of the icon is wrong, 2) the button in the array is not the button that is displayed on the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you're loading the file you think you're loading. Try this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("path/to/new/icon");
System.out.println(icon.getDescription());
```

This will be `null` if the file is not loaded properly. If this is your problem, try using an absolute path (e.g. `/home/waTEXmelon/program/blah.jpg` on Linux or `C:\\Users\\waTEXmelon\\program\\blah.jpg`) on Windows.

If you are expecting the icon to be in your classpath, instead use:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/class/path/to/icon"));
```

You should also consider [checking out `ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to help prevent this problem in your future, it's more robust than the basic constructors.

---

If the above is **not** your problem, consider that [Swing is not Thread Safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and you may be modifying the icon on a thread other than the Event Dispatch Thread. Try doing this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        buttons[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("path/to/new/icon"));
    }
}
```

---

If that *still* doesn't fix your problem, then the problem may be what @camrickr suggested, e.g. the JButton you're adding the icon to is not the one you think you're adding it to. To test this, both when you create the button, and when you update the icon, do a:

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(button[0]));
```

If this doesn't match, then the buttons are not the same button.

Comment: simply the reason was that i forgot stupid slash "/" in the path... why it doesnt even throw error that such file doesnt exist? i mean it was opening not existing file... like right was folder/4.png , but it was opening folder4.png... no error at all... thank u java...

Comment: Use ImageIO to read (and write) images if you want errors thrown when the file path is wrong.  You should read all the images you want to use before you start your Java application.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Added a sentence to that effect